# How to declare a worksheet name as wildcard?

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I have a worksheet named "Photo Sheet" that i would like to declare in my codes.

```
Const myWorksheet = "Photo Sheet"
```

My question, if i have another sheet called "Photo Sheet (2)" is there a way to declare the variable as wildcard that would take any sheet starting with "Photo Sheet*" ?

Comment: FWIW the "Worksheet" identifier normally refers to the type `Excel.Worksheet`. By declaring a constant with that identifier, you potentially "hide" the `Excel.Worksheet` type and confuse either the reader, or VBA itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite clear what you want to do, but you can iterate over the worksheets, using the `Like` operator to select the ones which have the appropriate name:

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name Like "Photo Sheet*" Then Debug.Print ws.Name
    Next ws
End Sub
```

This will print the names of all worksheets that begin "Photo Sheet". Of course, rather than printing their names you could e.g. put these worksheets in a collection for further processing.

Comment: Lol - beat me by 41 seconds.

Comment: @Comintern in VBA there is often a fairly straightforward way to approach a given problem, one which occurs to most experienced VBA programmers almost instantly.

Comment: I only need to set my variable to whatever the sheet name is such as "Photo Sheet (2)" if it contained "Photo Sheet" Thanks

Comment: @thisguyAgain yes, but avoid using `Worksheet` as the name of your variable, as it conflicts with Excel's `Worksheet` type.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't if you use an equity operator for testing it, but you can do something similar with `Like`:

```
Const SHEET_NAME = "Photo Sheet*"

Sub WhateverYourThingDoes()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws in Worksheets
        If ws.Name Like SHEET_NAME Then
            'Your code here.
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: this is missing the loop, so `ws is Nothing`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a wildcard to declare a worksheet directly, so no `set shtPhotos = Sheets(Worksheet & "*")`. A declaration like that has to be unambiguous or it would potentially return a collection, which can't be assigned to a non-array variable.

So, no wildcards. What you can do is loop through all your worksheets and check whether the sheet's name contains whatever text you're looking for:

```
Sub FindPhotos()
    Const csSheet As String = "Photo Sheet"

    Dim shtPhotos As Worksheet

    For Each shtPhotos In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If InStr(1, shtPhotos.Name, csSheet) <> 0 Then
            'do something
        End If
    Next shtPhotos
End Sub
```

This is going to look at every worksheet in the active workbook and see if their name contains the text in the constant. This will work fine if you want to perform the same steps with every worksheet that begins "Photo Sheets"; if you only want it to perform those steps with one such sheet, you'd add an `Exit For` after performing your steps:

```
    For Each shtPhotos In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If InStr(1, shtPhotos.Name, csSheet) <> 0 Then
            'do something
            Exit For
        End If
    Next shtPhotos
```

You could also look for a flag on the sheets that are found, so that only sheets that have, say, today's date in a specified cell would be processed:

```
    For Each shtPhotos In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If InStr(1, shtPhotos.Name, csSheet) <> 0 AND _
           shtphotos.range("A1").value = Date Then
            'do something
        End If
    Next shtPhotos
```