# Why would my Index formula with wildcard throw me a Subscript out of range error?

Tags: excel, vba

With this line, I'm attempting to find the sheet number of the tab that starts with the value of VarCellValue (which has been assigned accurately), with a wildcard meaning anything else after it is ignored: "fromWS = fromWB.Sheets(VarCellValue & "*").Index". Am I going about it the wrong way?

Then below in the If statements, I'd like to use the sheet number to pull data from those tabs.

```
fromWS = fromWB.Sheets(VarCellValue & "*").Index
sheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
```

Comment: You can't use a `*` to refer to a sheet like that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41124179/how-to-declare-a-worksheet-name-as-wildcard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your below line

```
fromWS = fromWB.Sheets(VarCellValue & "*").Index
```

Expects either a 1-based index number or a string to identify the relevant sheet. You provide neither in this case...

Further;

As `fromWS` is an object it needs to be `Set` to a WorkSheet object for the rest of your code to work `.Index` will return an integer not a WorkSheet object.

So it should be either

```
Set fromWS = fromWB.Sheets(VarCellValue) 'where VarCellValue is an integer
```

or

```
Set fromWS = fromWB.Sheets("Your Sheet Name") 'with a string identifying the name of the sheet
```

As per @BigBen comments you can loop through the sheets to determine which sheet names comply with your initial `VarCellValue & "*"` wildcard comparison and when they do, then run your method accordingly.